# How to pass optional value/parameter in python

Tags: python, path

I want to have the parameter for `childDir` to be optional.

```
def saveFile(parentDir, *childDir, fileName):
    # directory to store data
    DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent/parentDir/childDir/fileName
    # create dir_path if it does not exist
    Path(DIR_PATH).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    return DIR_PATH

saveFile("dirName", "dir", "test.py")
```

I'm getting an error

> TypeError: saveFile() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'fileName'

Answer (score 0):

You might have to call the function like this:

```
print(saveFile("dirName", "dir", fileName="test.py"))
```

Since `childDir` has a `*` in front of it, it will think the `"test.py"` argument is supposed to be one of the `childDir`s, so the only way here is to assign `"test.py"` argument to `fileName` by writing it out.

Comment: When i added ``*childDir`` and tried running using your recommendation, i got an error ``DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent/parentDir/childDir/fileName       
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'WindowsPath' and 'tuple'``. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ShadowWalker That's the problem with your code, not my fix, I have no way of fixing that, you can maybe accept and upvote my answer, and ask a new one?